# is the decorator pattern really necessary in this example?

Tags: design-patterns

Here is the problem statement

A restaurant has 4 Pizza bases:

Whole Wheat Pizza
Wood Fire Pizza
Cheese Filled Pizza
Thin crust Pizza

There are 8 toppings:

Tomato, Onion, Cheese, Pepporoni, Capsicum, Garlic, paneer, potato,

Calculate price of Pizza given a pizza base and 0 or more toppings with it (assuming each base and topping has some price configured).

My pseudocode solution to this was:

```
    public class Pizza {
        public int getPrice(base, String... toppings){
            PizzaBaseMap.get(base) + toppingsMap.sum(t -> toppingsMap.get(t))
        }



    Hashmap<String, int> PizzaBaseMap= {
        whole_wheat : 1
        wood_fire : 2
        cheese_filled : 2
        thin_crust : 4
    }

    Hashmap<String, int> toppingsMap = {
        tomato : 1
        onion : 2
        cheese : 4
        pepporoni : 5
        capsicum : 2
        garlic : 2
        paneer : 4
        potato : 4
    }

    //client Code 

    int Price = new Pizza().getPrice("whole_wheat", ["tomato", "cheese"])
```

Do I really need to use the decorator like the Headfirst desgin pattern book suggests in their example? The solution with the decorator pattern looks something like this:

```
    public interface iPizza
        {
             double cost();
        }

    //Decorator
    public interface iToppingDecorator:iPizza
    {
    }

    //Pizza types
    class WholeWheatPizza:iPizza
        {
            public double cost()
            {

            }
        }

    class WoodFire : iPizza
        {
            public double cost()
            {

            }
        }

     class CheeseFilled : iPizza
        {
            public double cost()
            {

            }
        }

      class Thincrust : iPizza
        {
            public double cost()
            {

            }
        }

    //Toppings inheriting Decorator Interface

    class CheeseTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
             iPizza pizza;
             public CheeseTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost(); 
            }
        }

     class TomatoTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public TomatoTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

     class OnionTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public OnionTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

     class PepporoniTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public PepporoniTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

     class CapsicumTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public CapsicumTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

     class PaneerTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public PaneerTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

     class GarlicTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public GarlicTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

     class PotatoTopping:iToppingDecorator
        {
            iPizza pizza;
            public PotatoTopping(iPizza pizzatype)
            {
                this.pizza = pizzatype;
            }

            public double cost()
            {
                return <price> + pizza.cost();
            }
        }

    //client
    static void Main()
            {
                iPizza pizza1 = new WholeWheatPizza();
                pizza1 = new CheeseTopping(pizza1);

                Console.WriteLine("Pizza 1 cost: "+pizza1.cost()+"INR");

                iPizza pizza2 = new WoodFire();
                pizza2 = new CheeseTopping(pizza2);
                pizza2 = new TomatoTopping(pizza2);
                Console.WriteLine("Pizza 2 cost: " + pizza2.cost() + "INR");

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

I just feel it's a complete overkill, my code is just as extendible as the solution with the decorator pattern. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is probably overkill in this situation. However, imagine a much larger application, with many more toppings; or where the price modifiers are more complex; or that you are building a reusable library.

In these cases, there are two strengths of the decorator pattern:

1. You can add and remove decorators from your code-base independently, because the behaviour of each is full contained in its class.
2. The way the object is decorated can be customized on a per-decorator basis

For example, suppose we had a special offer where any pizza with anchovies is 20% off (*don't eat the anchovies!*). With a hash-map this is quite cumbersome:

```
foreach (var topping in toppings)
    if (topping is Anchovies)
        price := price * 0.8
    else
        price := price - toppingCosts[topping]
```

With the decorator pattern, we can just add a new class:

```
class AnchoviesToppingDecorator : IPizzaToppingDecorator
{
    private IPizza pizza;

    public AnchoviesTopping(IPizza pizza)
    {
        this.pizza = pizza;
    }

    public double cost()
    {
        return this.pizza.Cost() * 0.8f;
    }
}
```

Of course then the order of decorator application becomes important. This can be enforced using the type-system if necessary.

---

You can enforce order on your decorators using the type system. Suppose all topping decorators must come before discount decorators. In our system, decorators accept their predecessor via their constructor. By changing the constructor type, we can restrict the decorators that we can build on.

```
interface IPizzaToppingDecorator : IPizzaDecorator
{

}

interface IPizzaDiscountDecorator : IPizzaDecorator
{

}

public class HalfPriceDecorator : IPizzaDiscountDecorator 
{
    private IPizzaToppingDecorator pizzaToppingDecorator;

    public HalfPriceDecorator(IPizzaToppingDecorator pizzaToppingDecorator)
    {
        this.pizzaToppingDecorator = pizzaToppingDecorator;
    }

    public double Cost()
    {
        pizzaToppingDecorator.Cost() * 0.5;
    }
}
```

Note how the constuctor takes a `IPizzaToppingDecorator` as opposed to a `IPizzaDecorator`. This ensures that `HalfPriceDecorator` can only be applied after a `IPizzaToppingDecorator`.

Anything else will throw a compile-time error; and we like compile-time errors because only we get to see them!

---

In this case, I think the Head First example can be improved upon with a fluent interface.

Wouldn't it be nice to be able to write this?

```
new WholeWheatPizza().WithTomatoTopping().WithCheeseTopping().WithPepporoniTopping();
```

This can be achieved with [extension methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method):

```
public static IPizza WithCheeseTopping(this IPizza pizza)
{
    return new CheeseToppingDecorator(pizza)
}
```

Comment: thanks, i really like the extension you suggested. But even if the number of toppings increased n fold, isn't it just a case of adding more entries to your hashmap ? Further we could do the same simple structure for every Product (say Coffee, instead of Pizza). Even if the end user configured the toppings can we not read the configuration into a hashmap and use that instead ? 
I agree that, "you can add and remove decorators from your code-base independently" but that only really makes sense if i were building a library where i don't expect people to change my base classes

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. I have added a second advantage to the answer that a hash-map could not cover (at least elegantly!)

Comment: hmm.. interesting point, that is exactly what i felt when i was reading through the example in design patterns. I'm not sure how you would fit in the "type-system" with the decorator pattern though .. any example links ?

Comment: Added a note to the answer